# (html/css)  full-width header/ footer help needed: white margin/ space on all 3 sides

Tags: html, css, header, margin, footer

This is a question helpful for any relative amateur/beginner who wants to build a simple html page with full width header and/or footer.

I am such amateur and trying to help a friend put a site together on zero budget.

I am using Kompozer/NVU for this, in case relevant for answer.

Please don't cringe when you hear/see how I am doing this, no idea how many html or css Gods I am offending ;-) My question will also be in plain English with few or no proper terms...you have been warned.

[note for mods: I will also dare to circumvent your spam protection newbie rule of max 2 links, for with my lack of programmer language one link says a thousand words in helping to clarify my issue, and thus I hope this is ok for everyone's benefit. no spam, promise!]

MY SPECIFIC GOALS:

I want my header and footer (on this page: http://abchealth.info/doc-mike-special/test/) to

1. be sticky/ always at the bottom
2. have 0 margin/ white space around it

and best

1. the ~760-960px content area to always be centered and
2. no scroll bar to appear in not maximized browser unless smaller than content area.

(I understand 3&4 [oh, second set of 1/2, this editor is editing me...] are separate issues, so no NEED to address them for the response to be complete, but it seems they'll come in pairs for many people, so why not try have it in one place...)

MY PROBLEMS:

Well, in short, none of the above is currently the case.

Header and footer are simple tables (will all 0px margins, padding etc), and my current research indicates that

1. it's a way outdated/ dumb way to do that (and I should use CSS box outside the body?) and
2. The white spacing around it isn't from the website, but the actual "parent", the browser.

WHAT I HAVE LEARNED/ TRIED

I am down a sad several hours of research and attempts, but it turns out google and stackoverflow work much better if you know the proper keywords...shocking, I know.

The most appropriate tutorial I seem to have found is at
http://www.sitepoint.com/css-extend-full-width-bars/#fbid=5AozZvdpZOs,

but I can't even seem to follow those simple instructions, as they seem to assume a very basic understanding which apparently I lack.

My following along looks like this:

abchealth.info/   testx/

The header solution worked fine BUT I am using the CSS body tag for the pages background image, so it's not an option for me and I need another way to do it (same as footer?).

The footer I may or may not have done correctly, I don't even know, I only know I have not been able to now actually make it look as I want/ add a horizontally repeating image for the footer and make it look as on my page linked to above (just without the white space/ centered/ no unnecessary scroll bar).

WHAT WOULD HELP ME THE MOST

The more 'plain English' your response - or even better direct copy/paste this here, use these settings for that CSS tag kinda thing - the more likely I wont have to come back with an even dumber question...

I hope I am not offending anyone with the level of my question, and if I did, you shouldn't have read to this far down and I still love you anyways :-)

In case it helps/ saves you 30 seconds, the css file is main.css in the "test" folder linked to above (not "testx").

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Michael

Comment: Please post you relevant code here on SO. To kinda answer your question: You have used tables for layouting purposes and now it bites you in the ass.

Comment: Something like this should get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/XCnJc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you [really shouldn't be using tables](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm) to control your page layout. Tables are fine for displaying tabular data, but certainly not a website.  I've thrown together [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qVu2P/1/) which should get you started on how to "kind of" achieve what you're looking for.  I'll try to answer any questions you have.

**Markup**

```
<div id="mastercontainer">
    <div id="header">This is the header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="innercontentmiddle">
            <p>This is some content</p>
            <p>This is some content</p>
            <p>This is some content</p>
            <p>This is some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footerclear"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">This is the footer</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

div#mastercontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}

div#header {
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 100px;
}

div#content {
}

div#innercontentmiddle {
    background-color: #0f0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}

div#footerclear {
}

div#footer {
    background-color: #00f;
    height: 100px;
}​
```

Basically what we're saying here is, we want our master container to be 100% of the width and height of the available space. It includes a header and content and a **footerclear** element (this is to prevent the content from your **content** flowing over your footer so set a sensible height on this).  Out **footer** element is outside of the master container and 100px into your mastercontainer (to prevent it being displayed off the page when there isn't enough content to warrant it). Your margin-bottom on the **mastercontainer** must always be the same as the height of your **footer** for this to work.

For further reading, I've always liked [this article](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/layout/) on layouts.

**EDIT 1**

If you're still getting spacing around your header and footer, then it's likely your BODY element margin / padding. Try the following in your CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all I would like to express my appreciation for this community and all of you responded so kindly to a stranger, especially one who clearly has nothing to give back to this particular community. I don't know if you still realize how special this is...thank you.

Terric, your fiddle seems to be the one exactly as I want it and your code has definitely improved what I do, thank you...however, I am still getting the same space around the header and footer (header/footer still not touching the browser), see http://abchealth.info/doc-mike-special/test2/. How do I fix that?

Comment: upon closer inspection, it does not seem to be the SAME space around header/ footer (it's more pixels, especially on the bottom), so probably a similar symptom, different cause?

Comment: @MichaelSolomon have you tried setting margin: 0; on the html and body elements in your CSS? It's likely these that are giving you your spacing.

Comment: Hmmm, that resolved 3 out of the 4, the space below the footer is still there...any idea?

Comment: @MichaelSolomon yep, you have a BR tag under your footer - remove this.

Comment: I also have a strange problem arising. WHAT I DID: Not knowing how to link the html to the external css stylesheet 'manually', I created it through the kompozer interface, named it main.css, opened it in wordpad and added your CSS. Upon saving, it forces me to switch from default "ANSI" because of unicode, and I selected UTF-8 (which in code of the original /test page, it seems that's what kompozer was also saving it as. RESULT: For some reason Kompozer now doesn't open my index.html anymore. No error message upon trying, just nothing happens. Any idea??

Comment: AND with your CSS added to my main.css, when I use Kompozer interface to add CSS to same-titled main.css (in same folder) it somehow lands in a different (to me invisible) stylesheet. From all I can tell I am made edits to same css file manually from notepad and via kompozer wysiwyg interface, but the effect is like I edited completely different files, only one being visible. or the same files in parallel universes ;-) HELP anyone? I am so confused and head spinning!!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think this may be what you're asking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/gHWVe/5/

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to Delan's but I already wrote all the code now so I'll post it anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/EB8GP/

Edit: hmm seems he removed his answer.

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <h1>MySite</h1>
</header>
<section>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</section>
<footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2012</p>
</footer>​
```

**CSS**

```
header,
footer {
    background: #06c;
    text-align: center;

    /* Makes the header and footer stick to the top */
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
footer {
    /* We want the footer in the bottom */
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
section {
    background: #eee;

    /* Centers the content area (margin: 0 auto) */
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    /* Here's the tricky bit, the margin-top needs to be exactly the height of the header (which may not be known) and the margin-bottom needs to be the height of the footer - I'm using an arbitrary number here and setting it properly with JS */
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
​
```

Unless you set a fixed height to both header and footer you need to calculate their heights with JS and change the content areas margin accoringly:

```
$(function () {
    var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
    var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();

    $('section').css({
        marginTop:    headerHeight + 'px', 
        marginBottom: footerHeight + 'px', 
    });
});​
```

Edit2: On a large site (not a JSFiddle example) I'd give those elements IDs and style as well as script those instead since you're likely to use more than one `header`, `footer` and `section`.